# Creating an ISO that a macbook can boot from

Tags: debian, system-installation, uefi, iso

Trying to repack an ISO with a preseed file to automate installation.

I have done this with a dozen laptops and works great. Until I ran into a macbook, where it does not work.

Originally repacking ISO with:

```
xorriso -as mkisofs \
  -r -J -V "Stretch Repack" \
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -partition_offset 16 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -isohybrid-mbr "/usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin" \
  -o $DEST_ISO \
  .
```

The standard debian live image mentions EFI when I boot from it on the macbook (and works great also) so I figure there is some EFI related issue here, so I tried:

```
xorriso -as mkisofs \
  -r -J -V "Stretch Repack" \
  -b isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -c isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot \
  -boot-load-size 4 \
  -partition_offset 16 \
  -boot-info-table \
  -isohybrid-mbr "/usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin" \
  -e boot/grub/efi.img \
  -o $DEST_ISO \
  .
```

Same issue, macbook can't detect my usb drive with my repacked ISO.

So then I found a forum post:

https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?pid=64229#p64229

And adapted it slightly:

```
xorriso -as mkisofs \
  -iso-level 3 \ 
  -full-iso9660-filenames \
  -volid "Repack" \
  -eltorito-boot isolinux/isolinux.bin \
  -eltorito-catalog isolinux/boot.cat \
  -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
  -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin \
  -eltorito-alt-boot \
  -e boot/grub/efi.img \
  -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat 
  -o $DEST_ISO \
  .
```

However, now xorriso complains

```
Cannot find in ISO image: -boot_image ... bin_path='/isolinux/isolinux.bin'
```

What? Why is xorriso looking in / now? I clearly passed `isolinux/isolinux.bin` in my command, not `/isolinux/isolinux.bin`.

Comment: The Captcha test does not let me in. So as comment:
Read paragraph 1 to 4 of https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO .
This explains how to repack like the original amd64 or i386 ISOs.
Your last try is quite near to that. But '/isolinux/isolinux.bin'
is missing in the ISO. I.e. './isolinux/isolinux.bin' is missing
in in your local filesystem.